# SQL - return a value referenced by initial value from same table

Tags: sql, union

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find any questions that help.

Here's an example of a table:

```
ID    Name        Parent ID
---------------------------
1     Ice cream   3 
2     Chips       4
3     Sweets      null
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write a single query which, given `ID=1`, will return me rows 1 *and* 3. Is this possible without making two queries?

Also, is there a way to return the information of the parent as a custom column? So, rather than returning 2 rows, returning the row `where id=1` with `parent_id=3` added on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` and `exists`:

```
select * from mytable where parent_id = 3
union all
select t.* 
from mytable t 
where exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.parent_id = t.id and t.parent_id = 3)
```

If you want to do this over multiple levels of hierarchy, then you would typically use a recursive query. The syntax slightly varies accross databases (and not all of them support recursion), but the idea is:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select * from mytable where parent_id = 3
    union all
    select t.*
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.parent_id = c.id
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: Thank you for this, really helpful. How about if I wanted to add the information from the parent to the child row? Eg, instead of returning two rows, return row `where id=1` but with `parent_id=3` as an added column.

Answer (score 1):

This is how a straight up noob would do it. Hold tight for someone to give a better way

```
SELECT ID, Name, Parent_ID
FROM table
WHERE ID = 1

UNION

SELECT ID, Name, Parent_ID
FROM table
WHERE ID = (SELECT Parent_ID FROM table WHERE ID = 1)
```

Comment: If you expect multiple matches you can swap `=` for `IN`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
select child.ID, child.Name, parent.ID as ParentId, parent.Name as ParentName
from T child left outer join T parent on parent.Id = child.parent_id;
```